# What is the name of the operator that translates from $X\rightarrow(Y\rightarrow Z)$ to $Y\rightarrow(X\rightarrow Z)$?

Tags: terminology, lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

Is there a standard name for the operator that takes a function $f:X\rightarrow(Y\rightarrow Z)$ and returns the function $f':Y\rightarrow(X\rightarrow Z)$ that satisfies, for every $y \in Y$ and $x \in X$, $f'(y)(x) = f(x)(y)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function $$\lambda f.\lambda x.\lambda y.f\;y\;x$$ of type $$\forall X. \forall Y. \forall Z.(X \to Y \to Z) \to Y \to X \to Z$$ is often called **flip**. This is the case in Haskell (see [here](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b+-%3E+c%29+-%3E+b+-%3E+a+-%3E+c&scope=set%3Aincluded-with-ghc)), and in some OCaml libraries as well (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627444/is-there-a-flip-function-in-the-ocaml-standard-library)). According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Combinators_B,_C), people call this function (or combinator) $C$ in the context of combinatory logic (that name sounds pretty random though).

Comment: And the function $\forall X Y . X \times Y \to Y \times X$ is usually called the *twist* or *swap* map.

Answer (score 2):

Given the tag [combinatory-logic](/questions/tagged/combinatory-logic), the answer in combinatory logic is [**C**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B,_C,_K,_W_system), i.e. "the **C** combinator". Obviously, this name is not self-documenting or going to be obvious in even a slightly more general context.